# C#: insert a PDF file into a specific place in another PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf

Does anyone know how to insert a PDF file into another PDF file? But not just add at the beginning or at the end of the file. I want to replace/insert the pdf file with a placeholder, which is in the another PDF file.

Comment: Which PDF library do you use?

Comment: i use ironpdf; contacted them but they don't have such a feature either

Answer (score 2):

You need a third party library for this, like [ironpdf](https://ironpdf.com/).

Comment: i use ironpdf actually, but they don't provide such a feature

Comment: I have never used it, but looking at the documentation, you could easily do it with a little effort from your side (like looking for a custom placeholder in the text): https://ironpdf.com/examples/reading-pdf-text/ and https://ironpdf.com/examples/editing-pdfs/

Answer (score 0):

I use IronPdf for this using:
[IronPdf.PdfDocument.CopyPages](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_CopyPages_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Int32__)
with
[IronPdf.PdfDocument.InsertPdf](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.PdfDocument.html#IronPdf_PdfDocument_InsertPdf_IronPdf_PdfDocument_System_Int32_)

```cs
// PM> Install-Package IronPdf
// using IronPdf;  

var pdfA = PdfDocument.FromFile('a.pdf');
var pdfB = PdfDocument.FromFile('b.pdf');

var rangeTocopy = pdfB.CopyPages(2,3);
pdfA.InsertPdf(rangeTocopy);
```

I do however agree that a CopyPdfPage(PdfDocument From, PdfDocument To, Int Location, int PageIndexToInsertAt) would be really helpful.

See also:
https://ironpdf.com/examples/editing-pdfs/